# Cloud code returns null value in finding average ratings

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm having a class 'Ratings' in Parse.com for my iOS app. Ratings class has a 'placeName','rating' and 'userId' for the user who rated the place. I tried the following cloud code to get the average rating as given in the Parse Docs.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("calculateRating", function(request, response) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("Ratings");
    query.equalTo("placeName", request.params.place);
    query.find({
    success: function(results) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
        sum += results[i].get("rating");
    }
    response.success(sum / results.length);
    },
error: function() {
  response.error("movie lookup failed");
  }
});
});
```

I call the cloud code from my iOS App with the following:

```
 [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"calculateRating"
                   withParameters:@{@"placeName":self.place}
                            block:^(NSNumber *ratings, NSError *error) {
                                if (!error) {
                                    NSLog(@"%@",ratings);
                                }
}];
```

The console gives me a null value. The codes are exactly in the same syntax as in the Parse Docs.

I'm new to cloud code. Can anyone help me?

Comment: have u entered data into the class?

Comment: Yes. I have data for all placeName. I've calculated ratings without cloud code and it works perfect.

Comment: the place you are passing as argument is it present in your class data.

Comment: Yes. It is also present in the class.

Comment: hey ur code is correct can u post a image of ur parse dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. It was the key with which the cloud function is called.In cloud function it is written as request.params.place and it is called from the program with the key 'placeName'. I'm new to JSON. Thanks to Mr. Dheeraj Singh.